# How to tell PackageMaker to Execute a bash script after installation

Tags: development, xcode, package-management

I'm creating a new Installer using PackageMaker. I need to run a bash script after the installation is complete.

In the "Contents" column I have a folder, which is the folder I want to be installed on the target machine. Within the folder, there's a bash file I need to execute.

If I click on the distribution properties and go to actions, I can "open" a file as a "postinstall action", but it won't execute the script.

If I click on the Content::folder and go to "scripts", pick the directory containing the script and put the script name as "postinstall", I get a "could not copy scripts" error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your postfight script installed as a folder in a package? A common mistake is to forget to store the script since the linking just is a pointer so run something already in the package. It's hard for me to tell from the wording if this might be the case.

Comment: My minimum target is OsX 10.5. There's no "postfight" script, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I have just added a folder to the "Contents". Within that folder, a "configure" script is contained, which I need to execute after installation.